# Create Laravel route variables to update links site wide

Tags: php, laravel, routes

How can I create route variables (not sure if this is the right term) in Laravel so if I change a URL it gets updated sitewide wherever the variable is used?

**Example**

I currently have a route

```
Route::get('/services/web', 'Services\WebController@index');
```

and when I change it to

```
/services/web-design
```

I have to go find every page/view/component/etc that has that links to /web and make it /web-design.

I'd like to be able to put a variable where those links are so they all update together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes):

```
Route::get('/services/web', 'Services\WebController@index')->name('services.web');
```

In your view:

```
{{ route('services.web') }}
```

This way you can avoid having to change several instances of hard coded url's by simply using the route() function to generate them based on the name of the route.

Answer (score -1):

in laravel9
Route::get('/services/web', [Services\WebController::class,index');

Comment: Hi and welcome. When you share code here, a link to the source / docu is helpful, or you explain it with a bit of text